# Id for each cell in table generated by Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm using [this code](http://www.redips.net/javascript/adding-table-rows-and-columns/) to add columns and rows to a table.

Now I am trying to add an id to every generated cell, as in an excel table.

For rows I assign 0, 1, 2, etc. and for columns I assign a, b, c, etc. so the first cell will have an id of `0a` or `a0` or something similar.

UPDATE: [here is my actual code](http://jsfiddle.net/R2KjP/1/)

```
var table = document.getElementById("excelTable");
var input = table.getElementsByTagName("input");
var globalLen = input.length;
var arr = [], arrStr = [];
var numId = null, modStr = null, re = null, var1 = null, var2 = null, total = null, sign = null;

function createCell(cell, r, c) {
    cell.innerHTML = "<input id='td" + r + c+ "' type='text' onfocus='doEdit(this.id);' onblur='doUpdate(this.value, this.id);' />";
}

function addRowId(tbl) {
    return tbl.rows.length;
}

function addColId(tbl) {
    for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
        return tbl.rows[i].cells.length;
    }
}

function appendRow(n) {
    for (; n > 0; n--) {
        var tbl = document.getElementById('excelTable'),
            row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
            createCell(row.insertCell(i), addRowId(tbl), addColId(tbl));
        }
    }
}

function appendColumn(n) {
    for (; n > 0; n--) {
        var tbl = document.getElementById('excelTable'),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
            createCell(tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length), addRowId(tbl), addColId(tbl));
        }
    }
}
```

I am having problems assigning unique IDs to every cell. The ID must have one digit from the row number (1, 2, 3, etc.) and one digit, or letter from the column (1, 2, 3, etc. or a, b, c, etc.)

So at the end it will look like 11, 12, etc. or 1a, 1b, etc.

The ID will be assigned to an `input` that is in this cell.

My goal is to get the indexes of a cell (row and column) and to assign those indexes to ID.

Comment: you can try `yourcell.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");` for each cell you have and the `uniqueidentifier` can be derived from rows and columns as you mentioned.

Comment: Or `yourcell.id = "uniqueIdentifier";`. Please click "edit" and add your actual code to the question, don't rely on a link to an external article.

Comment: Nice twitter status. Wait... too long?

Comment: Where are you adding the Unique ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yourCell.setAttribute('id', 'a0');` Just generate the IDs from your loop-variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `yourcell.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");`

For `uniqueidentifier` you can get `rows[index]column[index]` which will give you the value for that Row & Column.

Comment: Can u give and example with this rows[index]column[index]?

Comment: I am on my way to work, if I get a chance I will show an example later on, If no one did it by than.

Comment: @RazieL aka ALieN something like `alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML);`